# Explain the following error in testng

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

> org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
>   2; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching
>   "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:324)     at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:109)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76) Caused
>   by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; The
>   processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPIData(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanPIData(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanPI(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)     at
>   org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)   at
>   org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)    at
>   org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:170)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:304)     ... 3
>   more

Comment: This is an XML parsing issue, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19898942/1106708) on StackOverflow.